# Create database tables in H2 Webserver fails with Syntax-Error

Tags: java, sql, h2

I created a Webserver via Eclipse using the H2 Database Engine:

My Code:

```
Server server = Server.createTcpServer("-tcp","-tcpAllowOthers","-tcpPort","9092").start();
Server webServer = Server.createWebServer("-web","-webAllowOthers","-webPort","8082").start();
```

Then I accessed it via my url and want to do some SQL-Stuff. So I tried to create a few tables:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS RATING;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS FILM;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS USER;
CREATE TABLE FILM (
   FILMID INT PRIMARY KEY,
   TITLE VARCHAR(255)
);
CREATE TABLE USER (
   MAIL VARCHAR(255) PRIMARY KEY,
   TITLE VARCHAR(255),
   LASTNAME VARCHAR(255),
   FIRSTNAME VARCHAR(255)
);
CREATE TABLE RATING (
   FILM_FILMID INT,
   USER_MAIL VARCHAR(255),
   RATING INT,
   FOREIGN KEY (FILM_FILMID) REFERENCES (FILM.FILMID),
   FOREIGN KEY (USER_MAIL) REFERENCES (USER.MAIL),
   PRIMARY KEY (FILM_FILMID, USER_MAIL)
);
```

The problem is, that only two tables are created: `FILM` and `USER`, but not rating.

The console output:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS RATING;
Änderungen: 0
(1 ms)

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS FILM;
Änderungen: 0
(2 ms)

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS USER;
Änderungen: 0
(1 ms)

CREATE TABLE FILM ( 
   FILMID INT PRIMARY KEY, 
   TITLE VARCHAR(255) 
);
Änderungen: 0
(1 ms)

CREATE TABLE USER ( 
   MAIL VARCHAR(255) PRIMARY KEY, 
   TITLE VARCHAR(255), 
   LASTNAME VARCHAR(255), 
   FIRSTNAME VARCHAR(255) 
);
Änderungen: 0
(1 ms)

CREATE TABLE RATING ( 
   FILM_FILMID INT, 
   USER_MAIL VARCHAR(255), 
   RATING INT, 
   FOREIGN KEY (FILM_FILMID) REFERENCES (FILM.FILMID), 
   FOREIGN KEY (USER_MAIL) REFERENCES (USER.MAIL), 
   PRIMARY KEY (FILM_FILMID, USER_MAIL) 
);
Syntax Fehler in SQL Befehl "CREATE TABLE RATING ( 
   FILM_FILMID INT, 
   USER_MAIL VARCHAR(255), 
   RATING INT, 
   FOREIGN KEY (FILM_FILMID) REFERENCES (FILM.[*]FILMID), 
   FOREIGN KEY (USER_MAIL) REFERENCES (USER.MAIL), 
   PRIMARY KEY (FILM_FILMID, USER_MAIL) 
)"; erwartet "ASC, DESC, NULLS, ,, )"
Syntax error in SQL statement "CREATE TABLE RATING ( 
   FILM_FILMID INT, 
   USER_MAIL VARCHAR(255), 
   RATING INT, 
   FOREIGN KEY (FILM_FILMID) REFERENCES (FILM.[*]FILMID), 
   FOREIGN KEY (USER_MAIL) REFERENCES (USER.MAIL), 
   PRIMARY KEY (FILM_FILMID, USER_MAIL) 
)"; expected "ASC, DESC, NULLS, ,, )"; SQL statement:
CREATE TABLE RATING ( 
   FILM_FILMID INT, 
   USER_MAIL VARCHAR(255), 
   RATING INT, 
   FOREIGN KEY (FILM_FILMID) REFERENCES (FILM.FILMID), 
   FOREIGN KEY (USER_MAIL) REFERENCES (USER.MAIL), 
   PRIMARY KEY (FILM_FILMID, USER_MAIL) 
) [42001-196] 42001/42001
```

What is wrong with the code? I don't really understand what the output wants to tell me and I cannot find any Syntax-Problems.

Comment: FOREIGN KEY (FILM_FILMID) REFERENCES FILM (FILMID)

Comment: That did it, thank you :)